# win7 laptop with SSD, 2 gig RAM: Should I use Pagefile or ReadyBoost?

Tags: memory, performance, ssd, readyboost, pagefile

Hi I just purchased an Asus 1215B laptop.  It is dual core, and has stock 2 gigs of ram.  Before the first boot ever, I imaged the drive, and restored onto a Corsair Force GT CSSD-F60GBGT-BK 2.5" 60GB SSD.  I removed all partitions except for the main c:\ drive.

My question is: should I use a pagefile, readyboost file or both?  I have used readyboost before on my desktop, on an internal SSD, and I got a performance boost.

I have heard on good authority that putting a swapfile on a SSD will decrease it's lifetime.  Since my laptop only has a single drive, should I be worried about this?  Also does a larger page/readyboost file equate to more disk writes?

Do you have any suggestion for the size of these files? I have 56 gigs usable space.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since readyboost is for disk caching, and your disk is very fast, I don't see how that can really help or hurt you.

A pagefile is very useful, and should you run out of RAM it will be essential, but even without that, a pagefile is a good idea. See [here](http://thessdreview.com/ssd-guides/optimization-guides/the-ssd-optimization-guide-2/) for more info (see item six).